# Deploy React App to heroku cannot connect backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my app which using node.js, react and MongoDB to Heroku; The deploy was succeeded; However, the website cannot fetch data from MongoDB.
The error is `GET http://localhost:5000/comment net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error`, I think it is because I don't have `node server.js` running in the backend. can anyone help me with how to deploy this correctly?
my pakage.json in the backend is

```
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix myprofile",
    "start":"node server.js",
    "server":"nodemon server.js",
    "client":"npm start --prefix myprofile",
    "dev":"concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix myprofile && npm run build --prefix myprofile"
  }
```

And my server.js is

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./myprofile/build')));

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB data connected");
});
const CommentRouter = require("./CommentRouter");
app.use("/comment", CommentRouter);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("myprofile/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "myprofile", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`));
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: localhost:5000 would point to your local machine.  If you want it to point to the server that your heroku app is on then you need to use the url of your heroku app.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but how can i use the url instead of localhost?

Comment: When you make a request from your front end you would use the url of your heroku app instead of localhost.  So if you call to your backend with your react app with `http://localhost:5000/comment` you would use `http://yourherokuapp/comment`.  Right now if you use localhost you are just calling port 5000 of your own computer which is fine for development because you are using your own computer but if you want to use a server then you need to make the request to that server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying this project to heroku, your `start` command and your `server.js` looks similar to [this example](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started) so that's a good start.

Are you setting your environment variables with heroku, specifically `process.env.ATLAS_URI`? I would imagine heroku doesn't know where your MongoDB database is located.

Comment: Thank you Moshe, I have created a .env file and write the ATLAS_URI link there under backend files. But the server still doesn't work.

Comment: is your atlas port 5000? should `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` be set to true?